# django-reversion didnt work with MultipleChoiceField?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-1.10, django-reversion

I have form with **MultipleChoiceField**. It shows me data from tuple **CHOICES**. Users select checkboxes and then I use that selected data to create new objects (in my case requirements) inside view. When I try to use django-reversion in my view it raise Error. Do you have any ideas why `reversion.set_user(request.user)` and `reversion.set_comment('CREATE')` dont work?

**models.py:**

```
@reversion.register()
class Requirement(models.Model):
    code = models.UUIDField(_('Code'), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    symbol = models.CharField(_('Symbol'), max_length=250)
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=250)
```

**forms.py:**

```
CHOICES = (
        ('A', 'Name A'),
        ('B', 'Name B'),
        ('C', 'Name C'),
)

class RequirementAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    symbol = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=CHOICES,)

    class Meta:
        model = Requirement
        fields = ('symbol',)
```

**view.py:**

```
@reversion.create_revision()
def _requirement_add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RequirementAddForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            group_requirement_list = dict(CHOICES)     # {'C': 'Name C', 'A': 'Name A', 'B': 'Name B'}
            symbols = form.cleaned_data.get('symbol')  # Selected values: ['A', 'B', 'C']
            group_requirement = list_group_requirement_form.save(commit=False)
            for symbol in symbols:
                group_requirement.project = project
                group_requirement.symbol = symbol
                group_requirement.name = group_requirement_list[symbol]
                group_requirement.pk = None
                group_requirement.save()
                reversion.set_user(request.user)  # ???
                reversion.set_comment('CREATE')   # ???
```

**ERROR:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\reversion\revisions.py", line 296, in do_revision_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\PycharmProjects\RMS\project\views.py", line 603, in requirement_add
    requirement.save()
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 796, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 833, in save_base
    update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 191, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\reversion\revisions.py", line 302, in _post_save_receiver
    add_to_revision(instance, model_db=using)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\reversion\revisions.py", line 212, in add_to_revision
    _add_to_revision(obj, db, model_db, True)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\reversion\revisions.py", line 193, in _add_to_revision
    object_repr=force_text(obj),
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py", line 76, in force_text
    s = six.text_type(s)
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type __proxy__)
[26/Apr/2017 13:17:43] "POST /ru/account/dashboard/projects/cdecbd12-80d3-4ecd-9c08-8edef5d7f850/requirement_add/ HTTP/1.1" 500 18847
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the problem. In my modal I use:

```
def __str__(self):
   return self.name
```

After remove django-reversion works correct!

Comment: You could try changing it to `return str(self.name)` if you don't want to remove it completely.